# Python read from file, split each line into different segments, assign to keys

Tags: python, dictionary

So, I'm very new at Python and I'm trying to do a tutorial of making the game Risk very simply where we read in a file and each line has 3 parts: the territory name, numeric id, and continent. So each line in the file would look like this:

```
Alaska, 11, North America
France, 15, Europe
```

The dictionary keys are already named "territory", "numeric_id", and "continent". What is the best way to split the line and assign each part to its appropriate key? I haven't seen a question yet about pre-named keys and assigning values to them after splitting a line. Why doesn't this work?

```
dictionary["territory"], dictionary["numeric_id"], dictionary["continent"] = line
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dictionary["territory"], dictionary["numeric_id"], dictionary["continent"] = line.split(',')
```

You almost had it, you just hadn't split the line.

Comment: Split on ' ,' (space before comma) or use a  .strip()

Comment: @michel.iamit ' ,' doesn't separate any of them?

Comment: Other way around: space after comma. Sorry. Working on smartphone... limited view ;-)

Comment: @chris your regex replaces spaces in `North America` with an empty string.

Comment: Guys, this is perfect! Thanks a million, it all worked!

Answer (score 1):

Use a split based on the comma delimiter. Something like this would work:

```
line = line.split(',')
dictionary['territory'] = line[0]
dictionary['numeric_id'] = line[1]
dictionary['continent'] = line[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the line using line.split(", "), which returns a tuple split along ", ", in which the values are the strings between the commas.

The way you did it has it attempting to assign the entire line to your three dictionaries.